# How can I write the javascript for changing the mat-slider labels with range?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, frontend

Initially, I am using a mat-slider I need to change the label as per the range. But I don't know how to write JavaScript for different labels can anyone help me as of now I am a Fresher.

[mat-slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Etm.png)
I need this one

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bkdwpj?file=main.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we have a "input", a good aproach is use or `[(ngModel)]` or `[formControl]` to asign to a variable the value of the "input". The advantage of use a [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) is that we can subscribe to valueChange. That's, each time the input change, the formControl change and, if we subscribe, execute an action. We can use [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) to make the subscription.

We are going to!!

```
  min = 0;
  max = 10;
  states = ['sad', 'medium', 'happy', 'great'];
  control = new FormControl(0);
  state$ = this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(this.control.value),
    map((x: any) => {
      return this.states[
        Math.round((x * (this.states.length - 1)) / 
           (this.max - this.min)) + this.min
      ];
    })
  );
```

See that you use "map" rxjs operator to transform the response to valueChange -the value of the FormControl- to a string. we get the Math.round to get a value from 0 to this.states.length - 1 and return the element of the array "this.states"

The .html

```
<div>
  <mat-slider [min]="min" [max]="max">
    <input matSliderThumb [formControl]="control" />
  </mat-slider>
  {{state$|async}}
</div>
```

the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-znyhwv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslider-overview-example.ts)

Comment: tq for the contribution

Answer (score 0):

**Template**

```
<h1>How do you feel?</h1>

<mat-slider min="1" max="5" step="1">
  <input matSliderThumb [formControl]="mood" />
</mat-slider>
{{ moodDisplayText$ | async }}
```

**Component**

```
const MOOD_MAPPING: Record<number, string> = {
  1: 'very sad',
  2: 'sad',
  3: 'ok',
  4: 'happy',
  5: 'very happy',
};

@Component({
  selector: 'slider-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'slider-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['slider-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SliderOverviewExample {
  mood: FormControl = new FormControl(1);
  moodDisplayText$ = this.mood.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(this.mood.value),
    map((value) => MOOD_MAPPING[value])
  );
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jf9iqa?file=src/app/slider-overview-example.ts

Comment: Tq for your reply